# How to match values in a column?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have a file `temperature.txt` with columns:

```
city 
avghigh 
avglow 
coldmonth 
coldavghigh
coldavglow
warmmonth 
warmavghigh
warmavglow
```

I need to return the names of the cities which have the same average low temperature.
I also have this function:

```
def run_query(db, q, args=None):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if args is None:
        cur.execute(q)
    else:
        cur.execute(q, args)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return results
```

all I got thus far (If it's correct is)

```
return run_query(noname.db, ('Select Cities, AvgLow from Table')
```

Comment: I don't understand a thing in your question. What is the relation between your text file and the SQLite DB? *"I need to return the names of the cities which have the same average low temperature."* -> The same as what?

Comment: I created a table in SQLite db from the info in temperature.txt. I need to return the names of the cities that have the same average low temperature. For example St. Johns: 0.8, Charlottetown: 0.8, Halifax: 1.4. I would need to return St. Johns and Charlottetown - because they have the same average low temperature.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, this can be easily done using a self join on the table to get matching AvgLow for different cities like this:

```
Select 
t.Cities, 
t.AvgLow         
from Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t.AvgLow = t1.AvgLow 
                    and t.Cities <> t1.Cities
ORDER BY t.AvgLow;
```

[**SQLite Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d283a/1/0)